# Get last entered word of RichEditControl

Tags: c#, devexpress

How do I get the last entered word in RichEditControl
here my code

```
private void richEditControl1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
    {
        int wordEndPosition = richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition.ToInt();
        int currentPosition = wordEndPosition;

        while (currentPosition > 0 && richEditControl1.Text[currentPosition - 1] != ' ')
        {
            currentPosition--;
        }
        string word = richEditControl1.Text.Substring(currentPosition, wordEndPosition - currentPosition);
        this.Text = "Last char typed: " + word;
   }
}
```

But when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> create new line, it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get a word whether  it is surrounded by spaces or new lines, as long as it is the last one? Maybe you should include New Line check in your While loop, so it doesn't check just spaces.

```
richEditControl1.Text[currentPosition - 1] != "\n"
```

or something alike. Not sure if "\n" will pass , since I didn't work with such examples for some time. It probably just didn't know what to do whit new line.

Comment: How about you replace new line with spaces and then do while loop ? I looked it up, almost a year ago same problem existed and maybe it's not fixed to date.

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q496730 place where I read this. Also, maybe it's not just "\n" but "\r\n", that's how they mark new lines in control.

Comment: Maybe `richEditControl1.Text[currentPosition - 1] != Environment.Newline;`

Comment: so sad! It's still failed

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richEditControl1.KeyUp +=richEditControl1_Key;
    }

    private void richEditControl1_Key(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        var currentText = richEditControl1.Text.Replace("\n", "");
        currentText = richEditControl1.Text.Replace("\r", " ");

        String result = currentText.Trim().Split(' ').LastOrDefault().Trim();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}| {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), result));
    }
```